# Sencha Touch 2.1 upgrade - Both the web app & mobile app give white screen on iOS Simulator

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, sencha-touch, ios-simulator, sencha-touch-2.1

After upgrading from Sencha Touch 2.0 to 2.1, I am facing the following problems in both the web app and the mobile app:

1. Web App:
   After opening the web app on the iPhone browser, if I click on the icon to add it to the home screen and run it from that icon, it gives a white blank screen. The app otherwise works fine, if I open it using the url on the browser. Not able to find out what could go wrong with the web app if I open it using it's home screen icon.
2. iPhone app:
   I use phonegap for both the android and ios versions of the web app. Android mobile app works fine on an Android phone or simulator. However, the iOS app just shows a white blank screen after the splash screen.

Would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Any error in the console ? Can we have access to the app ?

Comment: I tried using debug.phonegap.com but didn't get any error in console. Just saw this link here:http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248720-PhoneGap-Build-produces-broken-app-after-upgrading-from-ST-2.0.1-to-ST-2.1.                 wondering if the mobile app has to do with it. However, still not sure what's wrong with when launching the web app from it's saved icon on home page.

Comment: @Raj, do you have any progress with this issue? I have the same problem now, and can't find any solution...

Comment: same here... If you have any update please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lukas said, it was a problem of **Sencha Touch v2.1.0** release , which is solved in current **v2.1.1** release. I have just tested my apps right after update and all is working perfectly now.. You just need to update SDK files.

Here is a thread about problem: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?249335-White-SCREEN-OF-DEATH-on-launch-with-ST-2.1/page4

Link to download new Sencha Touch version: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/sencha-touch-2.1.1/

Answer (score 0):

The white screen is a problem with the "sencha-touch-all-debug.js" file in 2.1

It will be fixed in the next release in the next few days. (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?249335-White-SCREEN-OF-DEATH-on-launch-with-ST-2.1)

A workaround is to delete all classes in the "sencha-touch-all-debug.js" file starting with " Ext.device."

For example: `Ext.define('Ext.device.communicator.Default',{...});`